Flask and Twillio integration
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

@app.route('/make_call', methods=['POST'])
def make_call():
    try:
        # Make a call using Twilio
        call = client.calls.create(
            url="server_url",
            to=to_number,
            from_=from_number
        )

        print("Call SID:", call.sid)

        return 'Call initiated successfully', 200

    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception:", e)
        return 'Error initiating call', 500

def generate_twiml_with_audio():
    response = VoiceResponse()
    response.say("Hello! This is a test call.")
    response.record(play_beep = False,timeout=5, transcribe=True,action="/save_audio")
    # response.say("I will pause the call for 40 seconds for your status")
    # response.pause(length=60)

    return str(response)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def twilio_webhook():
    # Generate TwiML with the audio file URL
    twiml_response = generate_twiml_with_audio()

    return twiml_response

@app.route("/save_audio", methods=['POST'])
def save_audio():
    try:
        recording_url = request.form.get("RecordingUrl")
        recording_sid = request.form.get("RecordingSid")

        print(recording_url)

        # Check if the recording URL is available
        if recording_url is None:
            # Recording is not available yet, respond with a status indicating to retry later
            return 'Recording not available yet, please retry later', 204

        time.sleep(3)  # Adjust the delay as needed

        # Construct authentication string
        auth_string = f'{account_sid}:{auth_token}'

        # Base64 encode authentication string
        base64_encoded_credentials = base64.b64encode(auth_string.encode()).decode()

        # Include Authorization header in the request
        headers = {'Authorization': f'Basic {base64_encoded_credentials}'}

        # Download the audio file from the recording URL
        response = requests.get(recording_url, headers=headers)
        audio_data = response.content

        print(audio_data)

        # Save the audio as a .wav file
        audio_file_path = f"{recording_sid}.wav"
        with open(audio_file_path, "wb") as audio_file:
            audio_file.write(audio_data)

        print("Audio saved as:", audio_file_path)

        # Define a function to process audio asynchronously
        def process_audio():
            audio_output = user_chatbot_conversation(audio_file_path)

        # # # Start a new thread to execute the process_audio function
        audio_thread = threading.Thread(target=process_audio)
        audio_thread.start()

        # Construct URL for the processed audio
        # processed_audio_url = "output"
        # Construct TwiML response
        voice_response = VoiceResponse()
        voice_response.say("I will pause the call for 40 seconds for your status")
        voice_response.pause(length=90)
        # upload_file_to_s3(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)

        # Play the processed audio from S3 in the TwiML response
        voice_response.say("Thanks for your patience.")
        output = presigned_url()
        print(output)
        # response = MessagingResponse()
        voice_response.play(output)
        # voice_response.play(presigned_url())
        # voice_response.pause(length=10)  # Add a pause to keep the call active

        return str(voice_response)

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error saving audio:", e)
        return 'Error saving audio', 500

import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer
from botocore.client import Config

def presigned_url():

    s3 = boto3.client(
        "s3", region_name="us-east-2", config=Config(signature_version="s3v4")
    )
    bucket_name = os.getenv("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
    key = "audio/output.wav"
    url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        "get_object",
        Params={"Bucket": bucket_name, "Key": key},
        ExpiresIn=604800,  # URL expires in 10 years
        HttpMethod="GET",
    )

    print(url)

    return url

def upload_file_to_s3(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key):
    """
    Uploads a file from the local system to an S3 bucket.
    
    Args:
        local_file_path (str): Path to the local file.
        bucket_name (str): Name of the S3 bucket.
        s3_key (str): Key (path) in the S3 bucket where the file will be stored.
    
    Returns:
        bool: True if the upload was successful, False otherwise.
    """

    local_file_path = "/home/ec2-user/new_rag/output.wav"

    bucket_name = os.getenv("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")

    s3_key = "audio/output.wav"
        
    try:
        # Initialize S3 client
        s3 = boto3.client('s3', 
                          aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                          aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
                          region_name="us-east-2")

        with open('output.wav', 'rb') as data:
            s3.upload_fileobj(data, bucket_name, 'output_audio.wav')

        # transfer = S3Transfer(s3)
        # transfer.upload_file(local_file_path, bucket_name, "audio"+"/"+"output.wav")
        
        # Upload file to S3
        # s3.upload_file(local_file_path, bucket_name, s3_key)
        
        print("File uploaded successfully to S3.")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error uploading file to S3:", e)
        return False

I am trying to get the audio spoken in call and record that and send user_chatbot_conversation to this function and get the output url i then upload it to s3 and then i need to play back the audio in the same call.
But here when i use this code it just runs the presigned url function first itself before the audio being generated,in this case if i remove that 90 seconds pause the call gets cutted before the audio function runs so i need to run it parrely and pause the call and after 90 seconds i need to play the output audio to the call.
the only thing is voice_response.play(output) , i am giving the url of s3 to this play funtion but still it dosen't playing the audio
